# Can't extending a remote graphql nested input type

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

graphql service 1 type defs:

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Post {
    postId: ID!
    postTitle: String!
    postContent: String!
    postAuthorId: ID
  }

  input PostTag {
    name: String!
  }

  input PostInput {
    postTitle: String!
    postContent: String!
    postAuthorId: ID!
    postTags: [PostTag!]!
  }

  type CommonResponse {
    code: Int!
    message: String!
  }

  type Query {
    posts: [Post]!
  }

  type Mutation {
    addPost(post: PostInput): CommonResponse!
  }
`;

export { typeDefs };
```

Now, graphql service 2 wants to extend `PostTag` input type from graphql service 1 like this:

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

const typeDefs = gql`
  extend input PostTag {
    color: String
  }
`;

export { typeDefs };
```

I print stitching schema, it's correct.

```sh
enum CacheControlScope {
  PUBLIC
  PRIVATE
}

type CommonResponse {
  code: Int!
  message: String!
}

type Mutation {
  addPost(post: PostInput): CommonResponse!
}

type Post {
  postId: ID!
  postTitle: String!
  postContent: String!
  postAuthorId: ID
}

input PostInput {
  postTitle: String!
  postContent: String!
  postAuthorId: ID!
  postTags: [PostTag!]!
}

input PostTag {
  name: String!
  color: String
}

type Query {
  posts: [Post]!
}

"""The `Upload` scalar type represents a file upload."""
scalar Upload
```

But when client sends a mutation like this:

```
mutation{
  addPost(post: {
    postTitle: "ez2on",
    postContent: "golang",
    postAuthorId: "1",
    postTags: [{
      name: "222",
      color: "red"
    }]
  }){
    code
    message
  }
}
```

Got this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$_v0_post\" got invalid value { postTitle: \"ez2on\", postContent: \"golang\", postAuthorId: \"1\", postTags: [[Object]] }; Field \"color\" is not defined by type PostTag at value.postTags[0].",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 7,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "addPost"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "errors": [
            {
              "message": "Variable \"$_v0_post\" got invalid value { postTitle: \"ez2on\", postContent: \"golang\", postAuthorId: \"1\", postTags: [[Object]] }; Field \"color\" is not defined by type PostTag at value.postTags[0].",
              "locations": []
            }
          ],
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: Variable \"$_v0_post\" got invalid value { postTitle: \"ez2on\", postContent: \"golang\", postAuthorId: \"1\", postTags: [[Object]] }; Field \"color\" is not defined by type PostTag at value.postTags[0].",
            "    at new CombinedError (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/stitching/errors.ts:90:5)",
            "    at Object.checkResultAndHandleErrors (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/stitching/errors.ts:111:11)",
            "    at CheckResultAndHandleErrors.transformResult (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/transforms/CheckResultAndHandleErrors.ts:15:12)",
            "    at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/transforms/transforms.ts:37:45",
            "    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)",
            "    at applyResultTransforms (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/transforms/transforms.ts:35:21)",
            "    at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/src/stitching/delegateToSchema.ts:104:12",
            "    at step (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/delegateToSchema.js:31:23)",
            "    at Object.next (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/delegateToSchema.js:12:53)",
            "    at fulfilled (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/stitching/delegateToSchema.js:3:58)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you're actually stitching the schemas?

Comment: @DanielRearden Hi, man.  Thanks for the help. Here is my code repo for reproducing this issue. https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/tree/master/src/extend-remote-schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that `makeRemoteExecutableSchema` just "uses the [provided] link to delegate requests to the underlying service". When you query fields from the remote schema, it's delegating the request for those particular fields to the remote server, effectively rerouting the request. This is true whether you stitch the schema with some other one, or use it by itself.

Schema stitching allows you to combine any number of local *and* remote schemas. However, any remote schemas will still have their fields resolved by their respective servers.

Because stitching merges the provided schemas' type definitions, you can use the `extend` keyword inside one schema to modify types from another, even if it's a remote schema. If we extend an object type, we can also [add some resolvers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching/#adding-resolvers-between-schemas) to help resolve the fields we've added.

Extending a remote schema's input object is a bit different. There's no "resolving" input objects. Instead, all we do by extending it is saying "these fields are also valid". However, when we request some remote schema field that takes this modified input object as an argument, the resolution of this field is, again, delegated to the underlying remote schema. It gets the modified input object and when it validates it, it finds extra fields and throws an error.

In other words, it's not possible to extend input types like this. And consider, even if the request *didn't* fail validation -- even if you extend the input type, the original resolver has not been changed and so it necessarily won't know how to handle the additional input type fields anyway.

**NOTE**: If you do the above but with two *local* schemas, the extension should work as expected because there is no delegation in this case. You're still left with a resolver that doesn't necessarily know how to handle the new input object field though.

Comment: I got it. Very helpful explain. So the conclusion is it's not possible to extend remote input types? The choice is to modify the `PostTag` input type in service 1?

Comment: If so, apollographql or graphql should update their documentation about this.

Comment: Agreed, although you are welcome to submit a PR to them to that effect :P Keep in mind that schema stitching has been deprecated in favor of federation.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I know it. So, @apollo/federation doesn't support extend remote input types either, are you sure about this?

Comment: I haven't poked around the federation docs to know for sure, but I suspect not. Conceptually, it just doesn't make sense to extend another schema's input types without some mechanism for also modifying the relevant resolvers.